# Running asynchronous function with Python and Asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I just got started to AsyncIO with Python, i made a very simple test script to try to understand how does that work.

Here is what i tried:

```
import cfscrape, asyncio, json, time

BU = cfscrape.create_scraper()

async def run(market):
    
    try:
        # DATA RETRIEVAL #
        URL = "https://api.binance.com/api/v1/klines?&symbol={0}&interval=4h&limit=130".format(market)

        ResultRaw = BU.get(URL, timeout=(10, 15)).content
        Result = json.loads(ResultRaw)

        print(Result)

        time.sleep(2)

        print('Finished')
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


async def main():
    Tickers = ['BTCUSDT', 'ETHBTC', 'ETHUSDT']

    for market in Tickers:
        await run(market)

asyncio.run(main())
```

This script takes three parameters and executes a simple query to an API endpoint, then sleep and print `Finished`. The output will look like this:

```
Result
Finished
Result 
Finished
Result 
Finished
```

What i don't understand is the following: why isn't the output:

```
Result
Result
Result
Finished
Finished
Finished
```

It looks like the script is executing the functions synchronously, one after the other. Instead, i wanted to create a coroutine for each execution, so the three requests should have been executed at the same time (nearly). Again, i'm new to async Python, so what i'm saying is probably wrong, but can anyone help me out understanding this?

Comment: Your run function never awaits for another coroutine, hence it never "suspends" and continues to run until it returns. To make asynchronous HTTP requests, look at `aiohttp` module on PyPi

Comment: Also, with co-routines, you should await on `ayncio.sleep` instead of calling `time.sleep`

Comment: Thank you a lot. That's right, i need to use aiohttp. How can i make the run function wait for another coroutine?

Comment: waiting for a co-routine to finish as in `awaiting` on it? You simply say `await <coroutine>` . To wait for a coroutine that is already started use [asyncio.wait_for](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/)

Comment: Ok! But i am already using await on the foor loop, before every execution of run. Or am i using it in the wrong place?

Comment: That seems alright.

Comment: In addition to what Quanta already wrote, note that your `for` loop runs each `run(...)` in sequence. If you want `run` for various markets to run in parallel, you will need to run them as tasks, or let `asyncio.gather` do it for you by replacing the `for` loop with something like `await asyncio.gather(*[run(market) for market in Tickers])`.